# What condition for if statement

Tags: android

Hi i'v got two different activities sending a number to a third activity, where one of the numbers will be displayed and some calculations carried out on them, depending on what number came through

It was working fine when I had activity 1 going to activity 3, but now i have a second activity going to activity 3, I don't know what to do

What i'm trying to do is, if the number came from activity 1, id like to display that number do some calculations on it and display the answers, and if the number came form activity 2 do the same

Sorry if title makes no sense, haven't a clue what i'm talking about

`

```
`Intent sender = getIntent();
    `   
  if (sender != null)
    {
    int result = sender.getExtras().getInt("Result");
    answer.setText(result+"");


    a = Integer.parseInt (answer.getText().toString());
    total1 = (float) (a *0.0024); 
    sd.setText(String.format("%.1f" ,total1));

    b = Float.parseFloat (sd.getText().toString());
    total2 = (int)Math.ceil (b*8);
    cet.setText(Integer.toString(total2));

    }

    else
{
 int resultB = sender.getExtras().getInt("BResult");
     answer.setText(resultB+"");

     a = Integer.parseInt (answer.getText().toString());
     total1 = (float) (a *0.001); 
     sd.setText(String.format("%.1f" ,total1));



     b = Float.parseFloat (sd.getText().toString());
     total2 = (int)Math.ceil (b*8);
     cet.setText(Integer.toString(total2));

}
}
```

Comment: as you said that you are passing only ID then try to use same KEY

Comment: But is Result not the KEY

Comment: Accept if its working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Calling form `Activity - A`

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
i.putExtra("CALLING_FROM_A", "AResult");
```

Calling form `Activity - B`

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
i.putExtra("CALLING_FROM_B", "BResult");
```

Now `Read that Intent value` as like

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("CALLING_FROM_A")) {
    // your code here
}

else if(getIntent().hasExtra("CALLING_FROM_B")) {
// your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, saved me a lot of time, someone tried to explain the hasExtra to me last night, but seen it wrote down makes it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("Result")) {
    // your code here
}

else if(getIntent().hasExtra("BResult")) {
// your code here
}
```